Проблемка с кнопками в телеграмм боте
Я новичок в Python, учусь писать бота в Telegram
Возникла проблема:
Кнопки срабатывают только после 2-ух нажатий
Использую метод bot.register_next_step_handler(), залез в интернет и встретил библиотеку Telethon
Скажите, лучше использовать новую библиотеку, или можно решить проблему и тут?
Фрагмент кода ниже:
def on_click_1(message):
   if message.text == 'Профиль':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке ')
   elif message.text == 'Пополнить баланс':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке')
   elif message.text == 'Помощь':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В разработке')
   elif message.text == 'Магазин':
      bot.register_next_step_handler(message, market)


def market(message):
   markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Покупка аккаунта Steam')
   btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Покупка аккаунта PlayStation')
   btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Аренда аккаунта Steam')
   btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Аренда аккаунта Playstation')
   btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
   markup.row(btn1, btn2)
   markup.row(btn3, btn4)
   markup.row(btn5)
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name} выберете раздел магазина', reply_markup=markup)

Заранее спасибо

Так все логично: вы нажимаете кнопку, регистрируете следующий шаг, программа ждёт еще одно сообщение и только после этого отправляет новую клавиатуру.

а можно ли как отредактировать и открывать новую клавиатуру в одно сообщение? В других ботах все работает без повторных нажатий

Просто в функции on_click создавайте клавиатура, а в market обрабатывайте её нажатие ‍♀️
